# How to make an argument default if no argument passed?

Tags: python, argparse

I have a simple argparse script that takes two arguments; `--encode` and `--decode`. I want to make the `--decode` default if no argument is given. How can I do so?

I want this:

```
myscript.py --decode "some encoded string here"
```

to happen when I do:

```
myscript.py "some encoded string here"
```

by default.

Comment: What do you mean by 'make `-decode` default'?  You don't make arguments default, you give attributes in the namespace default values.  What do you want the namespace to look like?  That's what you will be processing with the rest of your code.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the `'store_true' action` on the [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#action), or even the [default keyword on the add argument method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method)

You'll need to implement some logic, but here the idea:

```
parser.add_argument('--decode', rest_of_options..., default=True)
parser.add_argument('--encode', rest_of_options..., default=False)

values = parser.parse_args()

if values.decode:
    do_some_stuff
elif values.encode:
    do_some_other_stuff
```

Comment: Then you'll need to use the `store_true` action, and also positional arguments http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#name-or-flags

Comment: Might also want to put these options into a mutually exclusive group so users can't do e.g. `--encode --decode`.

Answer (score 0):

In `argparse.ArgumentParser()` object when you use method: `add_argument` is a flag `default="some value"` for example:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--test', nargs='?', const=1, type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

output:

```
>python test.py
Namespace(test=None)
```

add the default flag:

```
parser.add_argument('--test', nargs='?', const=1, type=int, default=2)
```

after add_argument change:

```
>python test.py
Namespace(test=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `default` parameter to specify a default, along with `dest` to control the variable name of the option:

```
import argparse
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# --decode and --encode are usually considered mutually exclusive; this enforces that constraint
g = p.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
# Order matters: the first default for a given dest is used
g.add_argument('--decode', dest='action', action='store_const', const='decode', default='decode')
g.add_argument('--encode', dest='action', action='store_const', const='encode')
```

Answer (score 0):

This approximates what you want, except for the missing '--'

```
p.add_argument('action',choices=['decode','encode'],default='decode',nargs='?')
p.add_argument('astring')

In [8]: p.parse_args(["a string"])
Out[8]: Namespace(action='decode', astring='a string')

In [9]: p.parse_args(['decode',"a string"])
Out[9]: Namespace(action='decode', astring='a string')

In [10]: p.parse_args(['encode',"a string"])
Out[10]: Namespace(action='encode', astring='a string')
```

If you must have the '--', nneonneo's solution is fine, producing the same namespaces.  Both arguments write to the same destination attribute, and that attribute by default is 'decode'.

```
p.add_argument('--decode', dest='action', action='store_const', const='decode', default='decode')
p.add_argument('--encode', dest='action', action='store_const', const='encode')
```

If you don't use a mutually exclusive group, the last argument will have final say (`'--decode --encode "a string to be encoded"'`)